# My projectile won't collide on tile palette walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a quick top down 2D diablo like on unity.

And my bullet won't collide with my walls made with tile palette. They are just passing through. Can't figure out why after some hours of googling.

Both have their collider2D on and i already made the kunai collider work great against enemies.

Thanks for every help !

Have a great day

Here are the projectile script and a little one i tried for the wall grid.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public int damage;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "wall")
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WallsDestroys : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Projectile")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

[Kunais prefab window's that are instantiated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLdRm.png)

[Walls window's inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvMka.png)

Comment: Transform.translate does not use physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answering ! Actually BugFinder say the right thing the issue was the Transform.translate wich not allowed for physics to work.

I changed the way the projectile was thrown and i manage to make it work.

Rigidbody2D was not the issue here one of my gameObejct had one.

Thanks for the help !

Bye until next time.

Answer (score 0):

A Collision with 2 GameObjects only stops them when atleast one has a Rigidbody2D.
I Assume the bullet nor the Tiles have a Rigidbody2d, so they will not stop when entering a collision.
I Assume it works against Enemys as they most likely have a rigidbody2d